# How to update html dropdown list value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that able to add new column and add new group to a html table. Currently only the latest column of drop down list are able to get the latest value from the `<p>` value. Only new added column are able to get the latest updated value.

**When I add a new group to `<p>` and `add column`, the drop down list able to get the value `test1`.**
[image]

**When i add another group name `test2` and add a new column , the latest column `Group2` able to get the latest value (test2)**
[image]

However when i click on `Group1`, the drop down list doesnt have the latest value `test2` and only show `test1`. So how can I make all the drop down list getting the latest value from the

values?.


[image]

```js
function createSelectEl(values) {
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.name = "group1";
  select.id = "groupId"
  // 1st option
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = 'Select One';
  select.appendChild(option);
  for (const val of values) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = val;
    option.text = val;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
  return select;
}

let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    const values = ["IT", "Cleaning", "Accountant"];
    const myP = document.querySelector('p#myP');
    var categories = myP.innerText.split(',');
    for (let j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
      values.push(categories[j]);
    }
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), createSelectEl(values), 'col');
    // createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'); // create DIV element
  //txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  // div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.appendChild(text);
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}

const submit = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const myP = document.querySelector('p#myP');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const values = input.value.split(',');

  if (myP.innerText == '') {
    myP.innerText = values;
  } else {
    myP.innerText += ', ' + values;
  }

});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Existing Group</h1>
<p>IT, Cleaning, Accountant</p>
<h1>Add New Group</h1>
<p id="myP"></p>
<input type="tel" id="group" name="group" placeholder="enter group name">
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>


<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

Comment: It looks like you only create the select when you're adding a new column. If you add a new option to the select, you need to update all selects in all columns. I.e. if you click on submit, get all selects and recreate their options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily [clone an existing DOM node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and call the parent node to [replace a child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) so with each new table column that is added a single new menu can be created and then cloned  -any existing menus will be replaced - thus all menus will display any newly added jobs/professions.

Rather than reading a dom node's textContent to generate the list of jobs a humble variable can be used to keep track of jobs/professions - this same array variable is then updated each time a new job is added using the inputs.

```js
(function(){

  const d=document;
  const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
  const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);

  const professions=[ 'IT', 'Cleaning', 'Accountant','Ferret Fumbler', 'Mouse Mauler' ];
  const tbl=q('#member_table');
  const form=d.forms.add;
  const group=form.group;
  const bttnsub=form.sub;
  const bttnaddcol=form.addcol;
  const bttnaddrow=form.addcom;

  /*
    utility to add new DOM elements
    t: type ~ the DOM node type/tag - defaault:div
    a: attributes ~ the attributes to apply to the new node
    p: parent ~ the DOM node to which this new node will be appended - default:null
  */
  const create=function(t,a={},p=null){
    let el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? d.createElement( 'div' ) : d.createElement( t );
    let _arr=['innerHTML','innerText','html','text'];
    for( let x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && !~_arr.indexOf( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || a.hasOwnProperty('html') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML || a.html;
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || a.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=a.innerText || a.text;
    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : d.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
    return el;
  };                


  const createSelect=( name, values )=>{
    let select=create('select',{name:name},null);

    // create the 1st hidden & selected option
    let opt=new Option('Please select','');
        opt.setAttribute('hidden',true);
        opt.setAttribute('disabled',true);
        opt.setAttribute('selected',true);

    // all the `options` will be appended in one hit
    let options=[];
        options.push( opt );

    // add new options to the array
    values.forEach( v=>{
        options.push( new Option(v,v) );
    });
    
    // splat - add all the options
    select.append( ...options );
    return select;  
  };



  const appendColumn=(e)=>{
    let sel=createSelect('profession',professions);
    let cell;

    // replace existing menus with newly generated menu containing ALL professions.
    qa('select',tbl).forEach(select=>{
      select.parentNode.replaceChild( sel.cloneNode( true ), select );
    });

    // create the new cell and add new menu into each row.
    qa('tr',tbl).forEach(tr=>{
      let b=tr.classList.contains('headers');
      let content=b ? 'Profession' : sel.cloneNode( true );
      let node=b ? create('th',{},tr) : create('td',{},tr);

      createCell( node, content, 'col' );
    });
  };

  const appendRow=(e)=>{
    let row=q('tr:last-of-type',tbl).cloneNode(true);

    q('td:nth-of-type(1)',row).textContent=form.company.value;
    q('td:nth-of-type(2)',row).textContent=form.contact.value;
    q('td:nth-of-type(3)',row).textContent=form.country.value;

    tbl.appendChild( row );
  };


  const createCell=(parent,content,style)=>{
    let div=create('div',{'class':style},parent);
        div.append(content);
    return div;
  };

  const addprofession=()=>{
    professions.push( group.value );
    displayprofessions();

    let sel=createSelect('profession',professions);
    qa('select',tbl).forEach(select=>{
      select.parentNode.replaceChild( sel.cloneNode( true ), select );
    });

    group.value='';
    group.focus();
  };

  const displayprofessions=()=>{
    q('section#existing p').textContent=professions.join(', ');
  };



  // add existing professions to displayed data
  displayprofessions();


  // add the event listeners
  bttnaddcol.addEventListener('click',appendColumn);
  bttnaddrow.addEventListener('click',appendRow);
  bttnsub.addEventListener('click',addprofession);
})();
```

```css
table {
    font-family: monospace, arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

input[type='text']{
    display:block;
    margin:0.25rem;
}
.bttns{
    margin:1rem auto;
}
button{
    margin:0.25rem 0 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr class='headers'>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>




<form name='add' method='post'>
  <section id='existing'>
    <h1>Existing Groups</h1>
    <p></p>
  </section>

  <section id='new'>
    <h1>Add New Group</h1>
    <p></p>
  </section>

  <section class='bttns'>
    <input type="text" name="group" placeholder="enter group name" />
    <button type='button' name='sub' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Save</button>
    <button type='button' name='addcol'>Add column</button>
  </section>

  <section class='bttns'>
    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="enter Company name" value='Acme Inc' />
    <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="enter Contact name" value='Joe Blow' />
    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="enter Country name" value='UK' />

    <button type='button' name='addcom'>Add Row</button>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: I figured out if user add column first and then only add group name, its still couldn't update the latest value.